# Character mapping

Tags: symbols, font-encodings

I have to write my paper using some slovene letters (čČšŠžŽ), but i'm having a hard time using the slovene keyboard layout as i mostly use the EN/US one and it's killing my production..

I remember i have been able to write those letter using 'c 'C 's 'S 'z 'Z using some package or something, but i can't find the original tex file to look it up.

Can anyone help me how to configure latex so i would be able to input those letter using the aforementioned method?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Doesn't there exist a simple way to change the keyboard driver from english to slovene?

Comment: The issue is not really with the changing of the layout, but with the impracticality of using the slovene layout, because i'm not really used to it anymore and most more used characters (as / \ [] {}) are not that easy accessible as on the US one.

Comment: Not TeX-related, but I find a character map with a search function very useful. You can also paste in U+030C, the combining caron, after your letters. On Windows, you can type it in by holding down Alt and hitting +30C, but on Linux, you can give it a more convenient sequence with your compose key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's already predefined:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}

\begin{document}

"c"C"s"S"z"Z

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanx a lot! My bad, thought it was the ' char. Working like a charm.